# Google Cloud insufficient auth scope to call cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to call a cloud function which shuts down a VM Instance with:

```
gcloud functions call stopInstancePubSub --data '{"data":"<instance data in base64>"}'
```

This works perfectly fine when I run it from my local machine or from gcloud console. But I need to be able to run it from inside the instance itself and when I try to do that, this is the error that gets thrown:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Request had insufficient authentication scopes.]
```

Essentially I want to be able to schedule a script to run daily (it'll run for about 2-3 hours). So I've used cloud scheduler to call the cloud function which starts the script at 12 AM every day, and it works, but I need to be able to shut down the instance (to avoid unnecessary charges being added) after the script finishes running. So, I need to be able to call the function from inside the instance itself.

Any other suggestions to achieve my goal would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the service account of your VM and what is its roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to Allow full access to all Cloud APIs on the instance that runs as a service account [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes).

Then assign the necessary roles to the service account to call the cloud function (roles/cloudfunctions.invoker).

> To change scopes, in the Access scopes section, set the appropriate
>   scopes for your needs. As a best practice, specify only the access
>   scopes that your VM instance requires. If you're not sure of the
>   proper access scopes to set, choose Allow full access to all Cloud
>   APIs and then make sure to restrict access by setting IAM roles.